# Isomorphism between the tensor-product of $\mathbb{Z}^m$ and gaussian rationals to $\mathbb{Q}^m$

Tags: tensor-products

Assume that $\mathbb{Z}^m$ has a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module structure. How can one realize that
$$\mathbb{Z}^m \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[i]} \mathbb{Q}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}^m \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}?$$